# I need a formula to convert dates into year-based seasons

Tags: formula, spreadsheet, apple-numbers

I'm using Apple Numbers and need a formula to convert a date in DD/MM/YYYY format to a season format in YYYY/YY.

I also need it to work based on a date range between 01/07/**** and 30/06/****.

For example:

14/07/2006 would be 2006/07 season.
04/04/2000 would be 1999/00 season.
23/11/1996 would be 1996/97 season.

And so on. Can anybody help with that?